# iOS App Store - how does localized language settings work?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, store

I recently released an app on Apples App Store and currently have it available in 2 languages, Swedish & English(U.S.). So my question is, what language will be presented to other English speaking countries since I picked English(U.S.)?. Do I have to add a description for all of them, for example, Australia & the U.K to avoid displaying the Swedish version of the app in the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the default language you set for your app. If you picked English as a default language then all descriptions will be in English on every store.

And if you want to have a swedish description. Choose English as the default language and then add the swedish language in the country list in the top right corner (click the + button) and add the swedish description.

Comment: Thank you! I had already set the primary language to Swedish but it was easy to change.But one thing I noticed was that even though I'm in the Swedish App Store and the Swedish screen shots are displayed to me, it says to the user that the language is set to English? Is there any way to change that or do I just have to accept it like that?

Comment: The language set to English (on left side of the iTunes App Store presentation page comes from the language in the app, and not from the iTunesConnect info. Maybe your xcode projet or app target have english as base language for your app.